# Very fast webpage scraping (Python)

Tags: python, screen-scraping

So I'm trying to filter through a list of urls (potentially in the hundreds) and filter out every article who's body is less than X number of words (ARTICLE LENGTH). But when I run my application, it takes an unreasonable amount of time, so much so that my hosting service times out. I'm currently using Goose (https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) with the following filter function:

```
def is_news_and_data(url):
"""A function that returns a list of the form
    [True, title, meta_description]
    or
    [False]
"""
result = []
if url == None:
    return False
try:
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    if len(article.cleaned_text.split()) < ARTICLE_LENGTH:
        result.append(False)
    else:
        title = article.title
        meta_description = article.meta_description
        result.extend([True, title, meta_description])
except:
    result.append(False)
return result
```

In the context of the following. Dont mind the debug prints and messiness (tweepy is my twitter api wrapper):

```
def get_links(auth):
"""Returns a list of t.co links from a list of given tweets"""
api = tweepy.API(auth)
page_list = []
tweets_list = []
links_list = []
news_list = []
regex = re.compile('http://t.co/.[a-zA-Z0-9]*')

for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline, count=20).pages(1):
    page_list.append(page)
for page in page_list:
    for status in page:
        tweet = status.text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
        tweets_list.append(tweet)

for tweet in tweets_list:
    links = regex.findall(tweet)
    links_list.extend(links)
#print 'The length of the links list is: ' + str(len(links_list))
for link in links_list:
    news_and_data = is_news_and_data(link)
    if True in news_and_data:
        news_and_data.append(link)
        #[True, title, meta_description, link]
        news_list.append(news_and_data[1:])
print 'The length of the news list is: ' + str(len(news_list))
```

Can anyone recommend a perhaps faster method?

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with this. How are you running it, ie are you waiting for a results page while it is chugging through URLs? What exactly is timing out?

Comment: just updated my description with most of my code

Comment: My app is being hosted on heroku. If I ever increase the pages count past 1, it times out on me (probably for computing allocation)

Comment: How are you executing the code? Is it through a web request?

Answer (score 3):

This code is probably causing your slow performance:

```
len(article.cleaned_text.split())
```

This is performing a lot of work, most of which is discarded.  I would profile your code to see if this is the culprit, if so, replace it with something that just counts spaces, like so:

```
article.cleaned_text.count(' ')
```

That won't give you exactly the same result as your original code, but will be very close.  To get closer you could use a regular expression to count words, but it won't be quite as fast.

Comment: `a = ('word '*10000000); b = a.split()` returns almost instantly for me.. Why do you think `split` is a performance culprit? It's a built-in method I assume it's pretty well written..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the most absolute best you can do, but it will be faster. You'll have to redo some of your code to fit this new function.

It will at least give you less function calls.

You'll have to pass the whole url list.

```
def is_news_in_data(listings):
    new_listings = {}
    tmp_listing = ''
    is_news = {}
    for i in listings:
        url = listings[i]
        is_news[url] = 0
        article = g.extract(url=url).cleaned_text
        tmp_listing = '';
        for s in article:
            is_news[url] += 1
            tmp_listing += s
            if is_news[url] > ARTICLE_LENGTH:
                new_listings[url] = tmp_listing
                del is_news[url]
    return new_listings
```